# Python multiprocessing not working in unittest

Tags: python, multiprocessing, unit-testing

Running this in my unittest:

```
    # test thread safe
    def test_process(i):
        print i 
        time.sleep(1)
        print i, i

    for i in range(100):
        p = Process(target=test_process(), args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

But it runs sequentially:

```
0
0 0
1
1 1
2
2 2
3
3 3
4
4 4
5
5 5
6
6 6
7
7 7
```

I was expecting it prints all the single `i` first, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are prematurely invoking `test_process` in the following line

```
p = Process(target=test_process(), args=(i,))
```

Replace this line with

```
p = Process(target=test_process, args=(i,))
```

so that it will only execute once a new Process has been spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, I kicked off the function by giving `()`

this worked:

```
p = Process(target=test_process, args=(i,))
```